# Android and Iphone app function triggered by bluetooth device

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth

We are in the planning stages and our ultimate goal is to have a handheld bluetooth device trigger a function in our app. Can the bluetooth device send more signals than just vol up or down, or can our app simply intercept a standard trigger such as vol-up (if sent from a specific bluetooth device and use that signal to trigger our app's function.)?

Answer (score 0):

There is one framework called **CoreBluetooth** available in iOS to communicate with the bluetooth device. But the basic requirement for this framework is you should have bluetooth 4.0 i.e. BLE enabled device. Check this if this is helpful for you .
  The answer for you second question is you cant intercept the standard triggers like volume button events in your application. Because this uses the private apis of the apple . Apple  not allows you to access hardware element with the private apis . If you will achieve this by any way then also your application will not approved by apple.

Comment: So we could go with a bluetooth 4.0 device then we would be able to control the iphone app and make a custom profile for android devices as well, to handle that part of it?

Comment: @user1724365:sorry ,I am not getting you.

Comment: You have outlined the solution for the iphone, which is to simply use bluetooth 4.0. So I assume all that is needed is to make a custom bluetooth profile for android to make it work with that os.

Answer (score 0):

you can only trigger what iOS will allow you to, using CoreBluetooth for iOS. For android you have to bundle your app with your own library that's designed for that handset's chip and version of Android. There is currently minimal support for Samsung Devices running the latest version of Android.